# How to set csrf option in symfony

Tags: php, forms, symfony, csrf

I want to set CSRF error bubbling to false in symfony, on a form, using form builder.

I thought this would do it

```
$builder->get('_token')->setErrorBubbling(false);
```

but it gives me

The child with the name "_token" does not exist.

The csrf_field_name is set to '_token'. So, does the token get generated after my form building or something? Any ideas how I can do this?

many thanks
Dave

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable the CSRF token you have two options:

When creating the form on the controller pass an option:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new AcmeForm(), $acme, array(
            'csrf_protection' => false
        ));
```

Or as default option on your form class:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
   $resolver->setDefaults(array(
         'csrf_protection' => false
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but I don't want to disable it at all - that would have been easy. I want to set an option on it, as stated. Thanks, Dave